# Django website content built from 3rd party REST API

Tags: python, django, api, rest

I'm currently working on my first website using the Django framework. Major parts of my content is fetched from a third party API, which requires three API requests to said API in order to fetch all the data I need.
My problem is that this slows down performance a lot, meaning my page load time is about 1-2 seconds, which I don't find satisfying at all.

I'm looking for a few alternatives/best practices for these kind of scenarios. What would one do to speed up page load times? So far, I've been thinking of running a cronjob in the background which calls the APIs for all users that are currently logged in and store the data on my local database, which has a much faster response time.

The other alternative would be loading the API request data separately and adding the data once it has been loaded, however I don't know at all how this would work.

Any other ideas or any tips on how I can improve this?

Thank you!

Tobias

Answer (score 1):

A common practice it's build a cache, so you first look the data in your local database, if doesn't exists, then call the api and save the data.
Without more information it's impossible to write a working example.
You could make a custom method to do all in once.

```
def call_data(id):
    try:
        data = DataModel.objects.get(api_id=id)
    except Exception, e:
        data = requests.get("http://api-call/")
        DataModel.objects.create(**data)

    return data
```

This is an example, not to use in production, needs some success validation at least.

Comment: Thanks! However, as you already said, with more information it's hard to give more specific advice, so here's more:

The data that I'm pulling from the REST service is changing differentely.
API Call 1) This value might change once a day, sometimes, based on user action, it might change more often. Polling this once an hour should suffice

API call 2) This value might change every 2 minutes

API call 3) This value will definitely change every 10 minutes or earlier.

So what I want to say is: caching is probably not an option, unless I'm deleting data frequently. Slow experience still.

Comment: @TobiasZ Without a cache option, I think that the best idea it's use some async calls to get the api data and give a better user experience. But for that you will need some JS more than python/django. Better update the question if you need more info